# Will I be reported self employed

Tags: down-payment

If I was to buy a car and put 9k down and someone else give me a check for $8500 to go with the $9000 will it be reported

Comment: That sounds like a scam. Where/how do you expect it to be reported?

Comment: What does "$8500 Togo" mean?

Comment: This is a common scam - they will send a check for 8,500 that will eventually bounce. It usually happens to someone _selling_ a car. I don't know that I've seen it when _buying_ a car. MY presumption is that you'll send the money, the check coming back will bounce, and you'll never see the car.

Comment: if you have to ask whether something will be reported that means you know you are doing something illegal

Comment: duplicate of https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/156071/will-a-purchase-of-9500-in-cash-plus-8000-in-check-trigger-an-irs-alert-and-s